# How do I schedule content publication on a static site?

Tags: ftp, static-content, press-releases

How do I schedule the publication of new content (in this case, press releases) on my static site?

I am using FTP (FileZilla) on Windows 7 to do the job manually.  I am assuming there are some FTP clients that will do scheduling, or maybe there is some other way to do this?

Comment: Yes there are FTP clients that do scheduling, e.g. Core FTP

Comment: Is there a particular reason for the site to *remain* static? Once you start doing things like scheduling content, you're creeping toward dynamic behavior, anyway, so maybe should start looking at applying a CMS, even if a simple one. [Not intended as an answer to the immediate question, just noting.]

Comment: @Su' You're right of course, but until we get to that point this is what I need to do.

Comment: You know, I might have one of my clients do it this way, they keep 'forgetting' to properly embargo the press releases in their CMS. This might actually fix the problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd need a fully scriptable FTP client to do that, [NcFTP](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/), [LFTP (not sure if it works on windows)](http://lftp.yar.ru/), [Kermit FTP](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ftpclient.html), would work or [CoreFTP](http://www.coreftp.com/) as @paulmorriss observed.

[More info on a similar question over at serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/48651/know-of-any-fast-scriptable-ftp-clients-for-windows) which has a few other ideas like using powershell which might interest you.